# Filter deep nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some issues with filtering 2 arrays of objects. My goal is to filter the main array with another array, both arrays of numbers.

**Demo code below**

```
  partners?.map((e) => {
    let products = e.products.map(a => a.externalProductId)
    let porArr: number[] = active.map((a) => a.externalProductId);
    if (products.filter(item => porArr.includes(item))) {
      return console.log(e)
    } else {
      return console.log('bad')
    }
  })
```

`products` preview

```
[
    6268,
    6267,
    9745,
    9746
]
```

`porArr` preview

```
[
    6267,
    6270,
    6269,
    6641,
    9559,
    9560,
    9660,
    9663,
    9665
]
```

for some reason the func still returns always true in the if rule.

Any help greatly welcome!

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't return anything, it makes no sense to `return console.log(...)`. if you want to see what's being returned, use `console.log(e); return e;`

Comment: `products.filter()` returns the filtered array. An array is always truthy in JS, even if it's empty. So what do you expect the `if` condition to test?

Comment: What is the actual condition you're trying to test? If you want to test if any of the `products` are in `porArr`, use `products.some()`. If you want to test if all of the products are in `porArr`, use `products.every()`.

Comment: `: number[]` is TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: My goal is: if any of the products exists in porArr => do something, if not, do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not assigning the filtered array anywhere, you don't need to use `.filter()`. Use `.some()` to test if any of the array elements satisfy the condition.

```
if (products.any(product => porArr.includes(product)) {
    // do something
}
```